# Docusign brand name not showing on email

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to configure brands and I want the company name associated with the brand to show in the email sent to the signer.

I've setup my brand like this (on my demo environment):
[image]

I've also selected the option under Legal Disclosure to use the brand company:

[image]

However, When I get the email I'm still getting the account name (in place of the red highlight):
[image]

I expected to see "Test company sent you a document to review and sign" but I'm getting the account name instead "[[account name]] sent you a document to review and sign"

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the brand when you are creating the envelope. Each envelope can have a different brand. You identify it using the brandID.

Here is a [code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/brands-sending-envelope) in eight different languages to show you how to do that.

Short snippet from the C# code:

```
// Add the recipients to the envelope object
Recipients recipients = new Recipients
{
Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 }
};
env.Recipients = recipients;
// Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
// To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
env.Status = RequestItemsService.Status;

//Set the brand id.
env.BrandId = brandId;
```

Comment: Hello thanks for responding. I have specified the brand ID when I create the envelope but that is still not giving me the result I expect. Is this enabled for demo accounts?

Comment: yes, it should be enabled on all developers accounts (demo). 
How did you find the brandId? and how do you mean "result I expect"? what don't you see?

Comment: thanks for responding. I got the brand ID from the page where you edit the brand (its included in the first screenshot under company name) when I specify the brand ID its choosing the brand correctly but I'm not seeing that its using the Company Name which I specified on the brand which is what I was expecting to see. Instead I'm still getting the account name

Comment: aha, ok, the name that shows "<name> sent you a document to review and sign." is the sender's name, a person, not a company. You can change that by changing your name, this is not specified in a brand.